# Customizing autocompletetextview

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I need to implement a custom search functionality with autocomplete feature with custom adapter. I wrote my own custom adapter, Code is given below:
**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.emc.kulkaa.myfinancials.MainActivity">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edt_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_border_edittext"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/clear"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/white"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**`custom_item.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_color">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        style="@style/simple"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**`styles.xml`**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name = "android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/simple</item>
    </style>

    <style name="simple" parent="Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/simpleautocustom </item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**`simpleautocustom.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0dip"
        android:color="@color/colorBlue" />

    <corners android:radius="20dip" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dip"
        android:left="25dip"
        android:right="25dip"
        android:top="10dip" />
</shape>
```

**`java code`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AutoCompleteTextView mEdtSearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String arr[] = {"DSA LSA", "CHILD", "AICHILES", "CHILDREN", "FRANCE", "FRENCH"};
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_item, R.id.autoCompleteItem, arr);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEdtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edt_search);
        mEdtSearch.setFocusable(true);
        mEdtSearch.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mEdtSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mEdtSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Above code works fine, here is the screenshot of output:
[image: mywork]
However it doesn't still match expected output UI which is given below:
[image: expected output]
How can I change styles and custom shape so that I can achieve the output?

Comment: share R.layout.custom_item.

Comment: the below screenshot is your expected? and above screenshot is your current output. Are these true?

Comment: @ShivamOberoi: It is already in question, please check

Comment: @propoLis: Yeah, true

Comment: @propoLis: Sure... thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have tried something for you, hope it will solve your problem and you can customize xmls i.e background of `custom_item.xml` `TextView` according to your need.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#9A000000"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edt_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_border_edittext"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/clear"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/white"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_border"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**bg_rounded_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/hint_color"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/padding_less"/>

</shape>
```

rest your `MainActivity` (java) code is same, there is no need to set a `style` to your list item text view.
Here is the screen shot of the output.[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `styles`.

Only you should add  `android:padding="7dp"` to parent LinearLayout and  `android:background="@drawable/simple_auto"` to TextView in `custom_item`. It is working.

custom_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_color">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/simple_auto"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```